# What is the meaning of sudo sudo?

Tags: sudo

I am using Cloud9 for Rails development and it uses an Ubuntu environment. In the documentation about using the PostgreSQL database, it says:

Connect to the service:

```
$ sudo sudo -u postgres psql
```

What is the meaning of typing sudo twice?

https://docs.c9.io/setting_up_postgresql.html

Comment: Possibly the user is allowed to run the `sudo` command as root, but not the `psql` command as `postgres`.

Comment: @WarrenYoung Looking at the document it seems intentional that the user can get to root without a fight. The original user is probably considered an administrative account and so it was probably given `user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

Comment: Of course, not prompting for the root password for an account that has ssh rights is probably a concern.

Comment: I opened an [issue](https://github.com/c9/docs.c9.io/issues/158) (and made a hash of the pull request). Let's see if they fix it.

Comment: And it has been fixed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

sudo -u postgres allows you to impersonate the postgres user when running the command. Your user probably doesn't have that privilege, but root's does.

So the first sudo gives you root's privileges and the second sudo allows you (as root) to sudo -u to postgres allowing the command to be run as the postgres user.

Comment: +1: This could well explain the second `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

They have probably have only given your account sudo rights to the root account and so they think they need it to `sudo` over to the postgres user in order to get there.

Considering how many people right their rules, you might run `sudo -l` as the regular user to see if they gave you to access to all users or locked you down to root for some reason. I'm willing to be it's the former in which case you can leave off the first `sudo`.